# How many archers do I need to deploy to destroy an Archer Tower?

Tags: puzzle

I was playing Clash of Clans and came across this interesting problem. Consider the case when I'm attacking an enemy war base with an Archer. My archer can cause a damage of 12 hitpoint per second. The enemy's Archer Tower has a total hitpoint of 580, meaning it will take 580/12 hits by one archer for it to be completely destroyed.

The enemy Archer Tower can attack the archers too. The tower's damage-per-second value is 35, and the hit points of an archer is 28. So in a single shoot, the Archer Tower can kill one archer.

For example, if I deploy 10 archers to take out the enemy Archer Tower:

t = 1 second: 
10 archers attacking : 12 x 10 hitpoints total; Remaining hitpoints of Tower = 580 - (12 x 10) = 460 hitpoints

t = 2 second: 9 archers attacking (1 archer is dead by now): 12 x 9 hitpoints total; remaining hitpoints of tower = 460 - 108 = 352 hitpoints

t = 3 second: 8 archers attacking (2 archers are dead by now): 12 x 8 hitpoints total; remaining hitpoints of tower = 352 - 96 = 256 hitpoints

My question is:

How many archers do I need to deploy to destroy the Archer Tower completely(assuming the Tower attacks the archers at the same time)?

Comment: I hope I'm clear. If anything doesn't make sense, please do ask, and I'll try my best to explain.

Comment: What are the target acquisition dynamics? Do the archers focus fire? Is there a time of flight for the arrows? Will there be multiple wasted arrows if the target dies early? In these sorts of situations the target acquisition can make a MASSIVE difference: it could make the difference between losing and a swift victory. My advice would be to simulate this, because the crucial target acquisition and time of flight dynamics will simply be too complicated for any pencil and paper calculation.

Comment: It also has not been clearly stated how *frequently* each unit (and enemy tower) fires.  Yes, you mention they do 35dps, but often times a number like that is given in a game as an average and they in fact fire once every second and a half or once every three quarters of a second, etc...

Comment: @grdgfgr: No need to make it too complicated. The archers do focus fire. The time of flight is negligible. Since the archer tower will be attacking a single target at any given point of time, yes, there will be wasted arrows. I'm not sure how to run a simulation for a game like this, hence my question.

Comment: This kind of thing can be done easily by a spreadsheet, where each unit of time is a single line of the spreadsheet. (In this case, though, Hagen von Eitzen's answer provides an formula.)

Answer (score 7):

I assume that the Archer Tower cannot split its $35$ damage over several archers.
Then a group of $n$ archers can survive for $n$ seconds and cause $6(n^2+n)$ damage (this is because $1+2+\ldots+n=\frac{n^2+n}{2}$). So $9$ archers can cause $540$ damage and $10$ can cause $660$ damage before they are wiped out one by one.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming worst case scenario (tower perfectly focus fires your archers and tower wastes no dps)

You will need 10 archers and at least 3 of your archers will survive. If you have 9 archers, you will be wiped out if tower does a perfect job. If tower does not do a perfect job, 9 archers will likely be enough.

Comment: Can you explain the calculation?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/XXQtub8.png

I wrote a script and tried it for different archer counts. Each round takes 28/35 seconds, all alive archers deal 12 damage per archer and at the end of each round 1 archer dies.

Comment: I don't know what language is that. I tried to port that to PHP, but it shows 6 as the output. Can you maybe tell me what the problem is? https://eval.in/368730

Comment: Also, why (12 - i - 1) instead of (12 - i)?

Comment: because i starts at 1, but at i=1 no archers have died yet. (i-1)=archers that have died at that point. There is no  (12 - i - 1) in my code, there is 12*(n-i+1). The language is matlab, and matlab has a weird indexing. Indexes start at 1, not 0.